# How can I display the data piece by piece through the API?

Tags: javascript, button, bootstrap-5, fetch-api

I have 5 buttons. With Fetch, the API is fetched and written to the screen. I want the top 50 countries to be listed when I click on button 1. After that, when you press button number 2, the countries between 50-100 should appear on the screen. In this order, I want to remove 250 countries 50-50 when each button is clicked.

```js
const row = document.querySelector('.row');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')

fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
.then(res=>res.json())

.then(data=>{
    let card = "";
    data.map(item=>{
        card+=`
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card" >
        <img height="300" src="${item.flags.png}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">${item.name.common}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">${item.capital}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
        `
    })
    row.innerHTML = card;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    <section>
        <div class="container mt-5">
            <div class="row g-5"></div>

        </div>
    </section>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```